# How to use gsub and imap with a list of list

Tags: r

I have a list of list lst1, and each sublist also contain multiple dfs. I would like to replace `...`followed by any random number to "". How can I do that?

I am thinking of sth like:

```
lst1 %>% imap ( ~ {
  imap(.x, function(a, b){
      gsub("\\.\\.\\.::digit::", "", a)} )
})
```

But this get sth as list of list with character. So I must do sth wrong. Could someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::digit::` should be `[[:digit:]]+` or `\\d+` and the 3 dots can be simplified with a quantifier `{3}` after the `\\.`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst1 %>%
    imap ( ~ {
      imap(.x, function(a, b){
           gsub("\\.{3}\\d+", "", a)} )
         })
```

If the inner list is also a `data.frame/tibble`, we need to loop `across` the columns i.e.

```
library(stringr)   
lst1 %>%
    imap ( ~ {
      imap(.x, function(a, b){
          if(!is.null(a)) {
           a <- a %>%
             mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ str_remove_all(., 
                  "\\.{3}\\d+"))) %>%
             rename_with(~ str_remove_all(., "\\.{3}\\d+"), everything())
           } else a
      
           a
           
          })
         })
```

Comment: when I ran it, I got  ` Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "NULL" `

Comment: @Stataq can you show the dput of `dput(head(lst1))`.  THe mutate step is based on your description that there are data.frame in the nested list

Comment: I think itis likely becasue one of df is empty.

Comment: @Stataq do you have `NULL` element or something like `integer(0)`

Comment: It is NULL for the whole df. If I use normal list, your codes work. :D Is it possible to remove all empty df from the list?

Comment: Also, what if I want to remove `"\\.{3}\\d+"` from the col names from all df in the sublist, is it doable?

Comment: @Stataq try the updated for the NULL case